# How to disable all Scala type hints?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ Idea Community 2020.1.2 to write Scala code. I disabled all hints for Scala [image]

But the Editor still shows hints to me

[image]

My research showed that although all Inlay hints are disabled, but "Show type hints for" is still enabled. Since its grayed out I can't seem to disable it. [image] Any idea how to really disable all hints for Scala?

Comment: Try to search in "Action" panel (ctrl+shif+a for windows layout). Usually, there is the on/off switch for this kind of functionality.

Comment: @ArtemSokolov Thanks. I updated the example to make it more accurate. It is a problem with type hints

Comment: It is still a compilation error. If you write code that compiles, you wouldn't see those types.  The type hints feature adds type hints when code compiles.

Answer (score 3):

This is not "Type hint" on the screen. It is a compilation error. The returned type must be `Int`.

> but "Show type hints for" is still enabled

This is not true, type hints are disabled.